# Powershell compare two datasets using arrays or hashtable

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

[image]Using PowerShell I have two compare two datasets one is from CSV file and other is from a sql query result:

Sql query result:

| AppName | Metadata1 | Metadata2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| App1 | ab3245 | 1235 |
| App1 | ab4533 | 4645 |
| App2 | ab1234 | 4101 |
| App3 | ab4245 | 4101 |
| App2 | ab5245 | 6534 |
| App4 | ab5245 | 2312 |
| App5 | ab3245 | 1235 |

CSV data:

| Metadata1 | Metadata2 |
| --- | --- |
| ab4245 | 7890 |
| ab3245 | 3412 |
| ab3245 | 1235 |
| ab4245 | 7777 |
| ab4533 | 4645 |
| ab4533 | 2345 |
| ab5245 | 1929 |
| ab4533 | 4645 |
| ab9988 | 3344 |
| ab1234 | 4102 |
| ab9988 | 2233 |
| ab1234 | 4103 |

I need to compare for each AppName how the metadata1 & Metadata2 values are different with CSV file?

I tried storing data in two separate arrays and then tried comparing as:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $sqlarray -DifferenceObject $csvarray
```

But above code just returns the differences between two arrays.

Updating expected output:

This is to identify any changes available in CSV file but missing in DB.
Expected output for every App’s name metadata1 & metadata2 when compared with CSV file metadata1 & metadata2 only difference should display like below table:

| AppName | Metadata1 | Metadata2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| App1 | ab3245 | 3412 |
| App1 | ab3245 | 1235 |
| App1 | ab4533 | 2345 |
| App2 | ab1234 | 4102 |
| App2 | ab1234 | 4103 |
| App2 | ab5245 | 1929 |
| App3 | ab4245 | 7890 |
| App3 | ab4245 | 7777 |
| App4 | ab4245 | 7890 |
| App4 | ab4245 | 7777 |
| App5 | ab3245 | 3412 |

Comment: Having a real hard time understanding what exactly you mean by "how the metadata1 & Metadata2 values are different with CSV file". Please elaborate further on this or show a result you would expect

Comment: you want to know foreach app if those values are present in the csv on their own or are they relaed to each other - what output do you want?

Comment: Updated post with expected output. Trying my best to put the expected output table and explain the scenario

It's like comparing one to many(App1 metadata1 & metadata2 compared with each and every metadata1 & metadata2 from csv file) and return the differences. Likewise for all app2, app3, app4 and app5.

Comment: I see the update and still having a hard time understanding what exactly you want to accomplish though its a bit more clear now. Please explain in plain English what exactly you want to compare between the sql and csv tables. Is the combination of both values what you want to check against the Csv? or is it a lookup in `Metadata1` and check those values of `Metadata2` not present in Sql?

Comment: Same here - I can’t understand the process to get from the sql and csv data to to result set. Could you walk through the logic for, say the App1 data step by step and explain, for example, why does ```App1 ab3245 1235``` appear in the data, but ```App1  ab4533 4645```does not?

Comment: I *think* what you want is for each appname, find the unique metadata1 values in the sql (e.g. for App1 this would be ```ab3254``` and ```ab4533```, and then find all the rows in the csv that have those values in metadata1 and add them to the output with an appname of App1. (Basically, a join of the distinct sql appname and metadata1 columns onto the csv data, I *think*), but your sample output doesn’t really match that (see previous comment)…

Comment: Based on the data you are showing, you cannot get the end results you are after because of the duplicative nature of the shown attribute values of those array lists.  You have to join the attributes between them to map an AppName to all values for comparison. You just can't compare only Metadata1 and Metadata2, and expect the AppName to be part of the coming from the CsvArray, because you have not assigned anything to them. See my contribution in the answer section, though it's not exactly you end results, it is an explanation of what I am saying here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***As per my comment, using the datasets you provided.***

```
'Metadata1  Metadata2
ab4245  7890
ab3245  3412
ab3245  1235
ab4245  7777
ab4533  4645
ab4533  2345
ab5245  1929
ab4533  4645
ab9988  3344
ab1234  4102
ab9988  2233
ab1234  4103' | 
Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\CsvDataList'


'AppName    Metadata1   Metadata2
App1    ab3245  1235
App1    ab4533  4645
App2    ab1234  4101
App3    ab4245  4101
App2    ab5245  6534
App4    ab5245  2312
App5    ab3245  1235'| 
Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\SqlDataList'


   
'Metadata1  Metadata2
ab3245  1235
ab4533  4645
ab1234  4101
ab4245  4101
ab5245  6534
ab5245  2312
ab3245  1235'| 
Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\SqlDataListNoAppName'

$CsvMetaList = (Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\CsvDataList' -Delimiter "`t")
$SqlMetaList = (Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\SqlDataList' -Delimiter "`t") 
$SqlMetaList = (Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\SqlDataListNoAppName' -Delimiter "`t")
```

***Using Compare-Object of the arrays.***

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $CsvMetaList -DifferenceObject $SqlMetaList -IncludeEqual
# Results
<#
InputObject                         SideIndicator
-----------                         -------------
@{Metadata1=ab4245; Metadata2=7890} ==           
@{Metadata1=ab3245; Metadata2=3412} ==           
@{Metadata1=ab3245; Metadata2=1235} ==           
@{Metadata1=ab4245; Metadata2=7777} ==           
@{Metadata1=ab4533; Metadata2=4645} ==           
@{Metadata1=ab4533; Metadata2=2345} ==           
@{Metadata1=ab5245; Metadata2=1929} == 
     
@{Metadata1=ab4533; Metadata2=4645} <=           
@{Metadata1=ab9988; Metadata2=3344} <=           
@{Metadata1=ab1234; Metadata2=4102} <=           
@{Metadata1=ab9988; Metadata2=2233} <=           
@{Metadata1=ab1234; Metadata2=4103} <= 
#>

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $SQlMetaList -DifferenceObject $CsvMetaList -IncludeEqual
# Results
<#
@{AppName=App1; Metadata1=ab3245; Metadata2=1235} ==           
@{AppName=App1; Metadata1=ab4533; Metadata2=4645} ==           
@{AppName=App2; Metadata1=ab1234; Metadata2=4101} ==           
@{AppName=App3; Metadata1=ab4245; Metadata2=4101} ==           
@{AppName=App2; Metadata1=ab5245; Metadata2=6534} ==           
@{AppName=App4; Metadata1=ab5245; Metadata2=2312} ==           
@{AppName=App5; Metadata1=ab3245; Metadata2=1235} ==
           
@{Metadata1=ab4533; Metadata2=4645}               =>           
@{Metadata1=ab9988; Metadata2=3344}               =>           
@{Metadata1=ab1234; Metadata2=4102}               =>           
@{Metadata1=ab9988; Metadata2=2233}               =>           
@{Metadata1=ab1234; Metadata2=4103}               =>
#>
```

Point of note:
As expected, removing the AppName attribute via the ***SqlDataListNoAppName*** results are the same as the above, without the AppName of course.

***Ignoring the AppName attribute.***

```
ForEach ($CsvRecord in $CsvMetaList)
{
    If (($SqlMetaList.Metadata1 -notcontains $CsvRecord.Metadata1) -and ($SqlMetaList.Metadata2 -notcontains $CsvRecord.Metadata2))
    {$CsvRecord}
}
# Results
<#
Metadata1 Metadata2
--------- ---------
ab9988    3344     
ab9988    2233      
#>


ForEach ($CsvRecord in $CsvMetaList)
{
    If ($SqlMetaList.Metadata1 -notcontains $CsvRecord.Metadata1)
    {$CsvRecord}
}
# Results
<#
Metadata1 Metadata2
--------- ---------
ab9988    3344     
ab9988    2233  
#>


ForEach ($CsvRecord in $CsvMetaList)
{
    If ($SqlMetaList.Metadata2 -notcontains $CsvRecord.Metadata2)
    {$CsvRecord}
}
# Results
<#

Metadata1 Metadata2
--------- ---------
ab4245    7890     
ab3245    3412     
ab4245    7777     
ab4533    2345     
ab5245    1929     
ab9988    3344     
ab1234    4102     
ab9988    2233     
ab1234    4103 
#>
```

***Combining the two array lists to map an Sql AppName to the Csv then evaluate attributes Metadata1 and Metadata2, then just Metadata1.***

***Comparing both attributes.***

```
$CsvMetaList |
ForEach-Object{
    $CsvRow = $PSItem

    if(
        $SqlRow = $SqlMetaList | 
                Where-Object{($PSItem.Metadata1 -eq $CsvRow.Metadata1) -and ($PSItem.Metadata2 -eq $CsvRow.Metadata2)}
        )
    {
        (
            $out = [pscustomobject]@{ 
                        AppName   = $SqlRow.AppName
                        Metadata1 = $CsvRow.Metadata1 
                        Metadata2 = $CsvRow.Metadata2
                    }
        )
    }
} | 
Sort-Object -Property AppName, Metadata1
# Results
<#
AppName      Metadata1 Metadata2
-------      --------- ---------
App1         ab4533    4645     
App1         ab4533    4645     
{App1, App5} ab3245    1235 
#>
```

***Comparing one attribute.***

```
Clear-Host
$CsvMetaList |
ForEach-Object{
    $CsvRow = $PSItem

    if(
        $SqlRow = $SqlMetaList | 
                Where-Object{$PSItem.Metadata1 -eq $CsvRow.Metadata1}
        )
    {
        (
            $out = [pscustomobject]@{ 
                        AppName   = $SqlRow.AppName
                        Metadata1 = $CsvRow.Metadata1 
                        Metadata2 = $CsvRow.Metadata2
                    }
        )
    }
} | 
Sort-Object -Property AppName, Metadata1
# Results
<#
AppName      Metadata1 Metadata2
-------      --------- ---------
App1         ab4533    4645     
App1         ab4533    2345     
App1         ab4533    4645     
{App1, App5} ab3245    3412     
{App1, App5} ab3245    1235     
App2         ab1234    4102     
App2         ab1234    4103     
{App2, App4} ab5245    1929     
App3         ab4245    7890     
App3         ab4245    7777  
#>
```

Note:
In this scenario, one gets the Metadata1 mapping as expected, but that Metadata2, is not completely valid.

Hopefully, this illustrates the points I and others are trying to make in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Work with them like .NET objects.
If you are using **Invoke-SqlCmd** for the SQL result, and **Import-Csv** for the CSV result, and the parameters are correct, you should end with two arrays of PSObjects or PSCustomObjects.
You can run a foreach loop and compare each property between the two results.

Something like this:

```
$sqlqueryresult = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'YOURMSSQLINSTANCE.domain.com' -Database 'SomeDatabase' -Query "Select * From SomeTable Where SomeValue = 'SomeValue'"
$csvdata = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Path\To\Your\file.csv' -Delimiter ';' # Use the delimiter you have in your CSV file

foreach ($appdata in $sqlqueryresult) {
    $csvapp = $csvdata | Where-Object { $PSItem.AppName -eq $appdata.AppName }
    if (($appdata.Metadata1 -eq $csvapp.Metadata1) -and ($appdata.Metadata2 -eq $csvapp.Metadata2)) {
        return $true
    }
    else {
        return $false
    }
}
```